# laravel-7 : date_format jalali calender validation

Tags: laravel, datetime, datetime-format, laravel-7, laravel-validation

I'm getting a DateTime format from user input:

```
"Y/m/d H:i"
```

this is my validation:

```
$request->validate([
            'deadline' => 'required|date_format:Y/m/d H:i'
        ]);
```

but the problem is I'm using ***Jalali calender*** so 6th month of the jalali have 31 days. and user input will be like this:

```
1400/06/31
```

and now validator will throw an error because there are no 31 days in the 6th month of the Georgian calender.

how should I validate this date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use a rule over existed validation of laravel,

```php
php artisan make:rule [JalaliDateValidation]
```

if you are using [morilog/jalali](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) try to use checkdate function

```php
// Check jalali date
\Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::checkDate(1391, 2, 30, true); // true

// Check jalali date
\Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::checkDate(2016, 5, 7); // false

// Check gregorian date
\Morilog\Jalali\CalendarUtils::checkDate(2016, 5, 7, false); // true
```

Comment: how I can change the input date from the user to year and month and days? without security issues. many thanks.

Comment: when you getting the request from user, he/she send something like Y/m/d H:i, you can split it's value then check the date, it's obvious that you only need to verify year, month, and day. so first split the input, then validate it with checkDate function